# python selenium find_elements incorrect output

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python+selenium. I am trying to return some stuff with find_elements* functions - see code below. When I ask on length of the list, I can see that the number of items is correct, however when I print the content of elements I can see that each element contains the same values and it should contains different values.

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='some_class_name')]")
print(len(elems))   # returns correct number of items

for elem in elems:
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='another_class_name']").text)
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@href, 'https://some_web_page_name.com/')]").get_attribute(
        'data'))
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='other_class_name']").text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.` to reduce the scope of xpath to the current element children/grandchildren. In your case, the XPath is pointing to the first element on the page rather finding under the current `elem`
change code as show below

```
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='another_class_name']").text)
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[starts-with(@href, 'https://some_web_page_name.com/')]").get_attribute(
        'data'))
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='other_class_name']").text)
```

Comment: nice, that was quick. Thank you it works, but I am still confused anyway. My common sense says me that scope should be reduced by putting a dot on "elem." So from this point of view it seems to me some sort of duplicity. Nevermind. You was a bit quicker that @Assad Ali  ( I appologize - I did not realized first that one hour ago was quicker than 45min ago ) so I marked you as someone who answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

While looping or using find_element inside anther selector you have to add "." inside selector otherwise it will print same element multiple times

```
first_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='some_class_name')]")[0].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='another_class_name']").text
```

In your case use following code

```
elems = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='some_class_name')]")
print(len(elems))   # returns correct number of items

for elem in elems:
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='another_class_name']").text)
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[starts-with(@href, 'https://some_web_page_name.com/')]").get_attribute('data'))
    print(elem.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='other_class_name']").text)
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate that, I am sure there must be some explanation of using dot in xpath but over time you get use to it